# node.js parsing tags in html

Tags: node.js, html-parsing

I am trying to parse for a specific tag inside 2 websites.
I need to do that in an async way but to display the results to the user at the end.
I tried using htmlParser2 but I am not using it correctly. 
For example how can I parse all the h2 tags from the html...
Here is a code I was trying before:

```
var htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');

var parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    onopentag: function(name, attribs){
        if(name === "h2"){
            // 
        }
    },
    ontext: function(text){
            // 
    },
    onclosetag: function(tagname){
        if(tagname === "h2"){
            //
        }
    }
});

parser.write(html_txt);
parser.end();
```

I am quite new to node.js so any help will be more than great.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your code shows how to find h2 tags already. Are you looking for the element rather than the tag? Do you need the content of each h2?

Comment: Yes I need the content. I don't really understand what I need to do there and also how can I return it to the browser.